# Outbound ip address of server keeps changing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-14.04, ip-address

When specifying an API key for Google, you have the option to restrict it by ip address. I therefore restricted my API key so that it only accepts requests from ip-address 82.163.78.2.

However, whenever I attempt to do an API request to Google, it keeps saying "Access Denied", because the request is coming from an IP address that is different than the one specified.

The issue is that the outbound ip address used by the server does not seem to be the same as the ip address of the server it self.

In addition, the outbound ip address being used seems to keep changing.

Why is this happeing 
How can I fix this issue?

**Update**

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS server with [VPS.net](https://vps.net)

**Update 2**

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

gives me:

```
# Automatically generated by Cloud System
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 82.163.78.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 82.163.78.255
        network 82.163.78.0
        gateway  82.163.78.1
```

Comment: Are you sure the IP is *changing*? I suspect you're just mixing up internal/external IPs for the server.

Comment: Hmm. You should have a fixed IP address, then, and the behaviour you are seeing should not happen. You should first contact your VPS provider VPS.net. I've never heard of them doing anything like this.